# What does this export mean? Is this an object executing two functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

I came across this "higher order function". But I can't wrap my head around it.
Here's the snippet:

`addUrlProps([options])(WrappedComponent)`

Is this `addUrlProps` a function? What does it accept? It has two () beside it...

Comment: If you saw it coded as `var foo = addUrlProps([options]); foo(WrappedComponent);` would it make any more sense? `addUrlProps` is a function that returns a function

Comment: Since both answers right now are a little misleading in their terminology, I just wanted to add that this example is a function returning an HoC, which is another function that takes a component as its input and outputs a new component. The whole thing uses currying and can be explained simply as a curried HoC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In React it's called a higher order function (HOC), but really it's just borrowing an old functional programming concept. What it **really** is, is an application of [currying](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/curry-and-function-composition-2c208d774983).

---

### Simple Example

Let's say you want to create an `add2` and `add3` function. You'd do something like this:

```
// add2 = a => Number
const add2 = a => a + 2;
const sum2 = add2(5) // => 7

// add3 = a => Number
const add3 = a => a + 3;
const sum3 = add3(5) // => 8
```

The problem is this isn't really scalable. What if you needed to create `add4, add5... add100`? This is where currying comes into play;

```
// add = a => b => Number
const add = a => b => a + b;

// add(2)(5) 
const add2 = add(2);
const sum2 = add2(5); // => 7

// add(3)(5) 
const add3 = add(3);
const sum3 = add3(5); // => 8

...

// add(100)(5) 
const add100 = add(100);
const sum100 = add100(5); // => 105
```

Theoretically you could create an infinite number of `add` functions to your taste.

---

### Case Example

In your example `addUrlProps([options])(WrappedComponent)` is doing the exact same thing.

```
// addUrlProps([options])(WrappedComponent)
const foo = addUrlProps([options]);
const HOC = foo(WrappedComponent); // => A component
```

It's taking in `[options]` to create a function. Then that function takes a second argument called `WrappedComponent`.

Comment: Note that *a HoC is not a function returning a function*, it's a function that takes a component as the input and outputs a component. In React, that component could be a function or a class.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Yep a very subtle distinction that's true. I think in this case the OP is just unfamiliar with a function having two `()` next to it.

Comment: Yes, you're right and your examples are great, but the opening statement of your answer is still incorrect. React didn't renamed currying to HoC, they are different concepts.

Comment: Yep thanks for the feedback. I agree there is a distinction between the two, but they're still closely related. I firmly believe it's important to realize currying is a concept that goes beyond just one JS framework. It's in many languages.

Answer (score 1):

`addUrlProps` is a function that returns a function. In react terms it is a HOC. [HOC documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) The second `()` is invoking the function that is returned from the first invocation.

It is a shorthand for the following.

```
const func = addUrlProps();
func(WrappedComponent);
```

So instead of saving the result of `addUrlProps()` into a variable, it is invoked immediatley like so

```
export addUrlProps()(WrappedComponent);
```

Its returned value is the same component, wrapped in another component that is adding some extra functionality, or props.

It is worth noting that not all HOCs follow this curried pattern. A very popular library that uses this particular pattern is `react-redux` connect HOC. Don't be afraid to view the source code to figure out what is happening!

Comment: Note that *a HoC is not a function returning a function*, it's a function that takes a component as the input and outputs a component. In React, that component could be a function or a class.